# Can't login to Visual Studio Marketplace

Tags: visual-studio-code

**I want to login to [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/)**.
Running MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 using Google Chrome 62.0.3202.94.

It is basically stuck on this screen for a while...
[image]

...then it finishes with this.
[image]

Already tried several browsers, incognito / private modes without any success. Of course I contacted Microsoft first, without any progress on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added these DNS servers at System Preferences / Network Settings / Wifi / Advanced / DNS, and now it can resolve `login.microsoftonline.com` (so I can login to Visual Studio Marketplace).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was not the VS extension issue, it would be related to the network or the Visual Studio Marketplace site. I could visit it in my side, maybe you could test it later or using different network. View the result.

If it still has this issue, you could get support from the Marketplace directly using "General marketplace help" here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/billing/_shared/qa-marketplace-support

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I had it working on the very same network a months ago. I wrote a direct email to "General marketplace help" according your suggestion, thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

PC USERS: Check your Windows version

I resolved it today!! The problem was my PC was running `Windows 8.0` and since it is no longer supported by Microsoft apparently, you need at least 8.1 to access the marketplace. I had to run the updates for windows a few times, and then by the 3rd restart I was able to access an `upgrade to 8.1` and now I can access the marketplace in VS!!